# Problem adding initial migration and my configuration and services don't have references

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I just started learning how to create asp.netcore web applications using mvc 2.0 pattern...i encountered;Problem adding migration...and most of the configuration and services in my startup.cs don't have any reference hence they dont change color.I was told I have to install one nuget package but I already installed some...it is still not working. Hence I can't add initial migration. In the picture above I have included an evidence of the Nuget packages I installed on my system

Comment: can you add a screenshot or code? With exception

Comment: I can't put up pictures because I just joined stackoverflow and I was told I need 10 reputations to add pictures to my question but I added Microsoft.entity.framework. core , Microsoft. Entity.framework. core.tools  and Microsoft. Entity.framework. sqlserver all version 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my .netcore SDK software to 2.2 so I could run asp.netcore MVC 2.2 since all my nuget packages are versions 2.2.n....it is working well  and I've been able to add migration ....thanks to you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` in your project.

If you are using  asp.net core 2.2(2.1+), you do not need to add additional EF core packages which are included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage. The default .csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>aspnet-{Project Name}-{GUID}</UserSecretsId>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For asp.net core 2.0,

```
<Project Sdk = "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" >
  < PropertyGroup >
    < TargetFramework > netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-{Project Name}-{GUID}</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include = "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include = "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include = "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

You could show your .csproj file(Right-click project -> Edit csproj) and check the missing packages.

Comment: i have added the nuget packages and when i showed my .csproj file.... these are the packages i saw: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\libraryData\libraryData.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>    . i had to split them this way beacause i had no other way to show you....and still my configurations and services do not have refrence and i still can't add initial migration

Comment: Since your project targets in core 2.0, try to downgrade the packages to 2.0.x version instead of 2.2.x version as I suggested code like.

Comment: i have upgraded my  .NET core sdk 2.2.107 i think, and i was able to install microsoft.netcore.app 2.2 which solved the problem afor a short while... i was able to build the startup.cs file without any error but my virtual studio restarted for reasons i don't know and it was back to the initial error state...i can't build my startup.cs page again hence my configuration and services do not have references again